# Increase value from bindParam

Tags: php

I have searched and searched and can't find the answer to what would seem like a basic question.

I am trying to increase an existing value from a PDO parameter and can't figure out how I would do it.

```
$value = strip_tags($_POST['value']);
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE table SET value = value + :value");
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

I get no errors, but also no update of the table. If I replace `:value` with a number `12` it works perfectly.

So how do I increase the value from `bindParam`?

Comment: Do you need a `WHERE` clause on your `UPDATE`.

Comment: No I have no `WHERE` as there is no need for one, there is only 1 column in the table. However even if I add a `WHERE id = '1'` it makes no difference on the result.

Comment: Have you tried using a debug print to verify that the `value` param is being received correctly?

Comment: What does `var_dump($value);` reveal? I also don't know why you're using `strip_tags()` here.

Comment: I can't believe I am that stupid. Had my logic reversed. Your suggestions helped me track the issue. For some reason I jsut thought this was an issue with PDO and postgresql. None the less problem solved.

Comment: Great, but hard to say "how" you solved it.

Comment: The issue was `$value` was always returning `0` so no error in the DB but no update as anything +0 will not change. I had to fix the `$value` input so it didn't return 0. On a side note I use strip_tags on all GET and POST by default but that question actually caused me to examine the variable.